# IBM BladeCenter S storage module

Tags: raid, storage, ibm, bladecenter

I am new to this forum and have a question I'd like to ask.

I have a client who is running a BladeCenter S, which includes a 6-disk Storage Module (44Y1405/44E8057).

The problem they have is that when they switch the system on, everything is powered normally, however the Storage Module shuts down after a few seconds and raises the following alert:

"There is insufficient cooling available for the storage module. It will power down in five minutes if no action is taken"

There are no errors related to the power module. Everything else switches on normally: the blades, I/O modules and so on.

The system also reports that power is normal across the system and cooling is working fine.

Can this ever be a false alert and, if so, how can it be bypassed? If not, what are your suggestions please?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first thing IBM is going to have you do is update firmware.  And it usually works to clear weird errors like this (I have 14 BladeCenter H's and 2 FlexChassis in my data center).  Even on modules that have been running untouched for over 2 years weird junk like this still spuriously pops up (yeah, I know how crazy that sounds).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this isn't a forum, forums invite comments and opinion, we're very specifically a question and answer site.

Secondly have you checked that you have all fan modules installed and actually working? If they are all installed and spinning then you either have a problem with the storage module or the chassis itself - I'd get IBM involved as either will require hardware assistance.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and sorry for the misnomer. All fan modules are installed and working, there is even redundancy in that area and we have tried to change the placement of each module to see whether any combination yields different results. I will get IBM involved as you suggest, thank you.